# USB Hub with USB-A male input, will it damage my computer?

Tags: usb, power, usb-3, usb-hub

I bought [this](https://www.temu.com/goods.html?_bg_fs=1&goods_id=601099531417134) hub from temu.com recently and I actually **really** like it. I can leave it clamped on my desk with all my peripherals plugged in, and then just connect 1 wire when I need them. It doesnt float around my desk, and also gives an additional USB-C (which for some reason so few hubs do). ****What I am worried about is that it uses USB-A **in******, which seems to be a non-standard way of doing things, and potentially harmful. So here is what I want to know.

1. Is that still true with the USB 3.0 standard? (the inside is blue and the read/writes speeds seem to be faster than USB 2.0).
2. Would it help at all that I actually *dont* plug the USB A directly into my laptop (Dell XPS, No USB A ports) and I actually always attach it with this [this](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-adapter-usb-c-to-usb-a-30/apd/470-abne/pc-accessories?tfcid=39138382&srsltid=AfmBOoq7iveu_KQsVuhbm1uQKTnYWsTkiQpjywSK8U-4Szl9GSlguSbf0pg) dongle that almost certainly only supports power in, not power out... Or is this a actually a liability...?
3. Is there a USB C cable I can use that would work for me? So I can skip the dongle? (tried one that I had, it didnt work, but it wasnt USB 3.0)
4. What would the USB C-in, on the rear of the device be used for on this hub? What device would need more power? Would using it risk my laptop?
   (Seems to only support power in, not data transfer)
   [Link to Image](https://ibb.co/tPYLtK3)

==============
I found a few similar products being sold around the web.

[https://www.amazon.com/USB-Hub-3-0-Adjustable-Space-Saving/dp/B07RM6QWHP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RM6QWHP)

[https://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-Clip-Type-Desktop-10-32MM-Accessory/dp/B0C4TT3JFF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C4TT3JFF)

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Eterstarly-USB-Hub-3-0-4-Port-Aluminum-Desk-Clamp-Design-Desktop-Computer-PC-Table-Edge-Durable-Adjustable-Clip-Space-Saving-Mountable-Fast-Speed-Tra/5076612583

https://oricotechs.com/products/orico-4-port-usb-3-0-clamp-design-mountable-hub

https://www.orico.cc/us/product/detail/8420.html

==============
Similar question to:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/444283/why-is-usb-type-a-to-usb-type-a-never-used#new-answer?newreg=1f1b359f47534b3f86fd68e71de7abcf
and
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/644717/are-usb-2-0-type-a-male-male-cables-compliant-with-usb-specification

Any input would be helpful, Thanks in advance and sorry if it was covered a bit already in those other posts.

---

[For some reason they didnt like my question over at [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/):

> "Closed. This question is off-topic. It is not currently accepting
> answers. Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as
> this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics
> design."

If someone could explain to me how I can fix my question, I feel like it may be a better fit for there...]

Comment: Yes, a Type A connector for a non-host (or upstream) port is unusual, and may even violate USB standards. But what are you concerned about? If you try to plug a USB device into that port, nothing should happen.

Comment: Likely, the hub really works at slow USB-A speeds. As for connecting two PC's with that male-to-male cable, that could cause damage, because of the two power being directly connected.